# browser can visit the url but other application can't

Tags: information-gathering

I did simple 'intitle:"index of" xss' search and got this page with URL 'https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/codesnippets4all/xss-filter/'.I can see the IP on the wireshark and the conversation of machine and server with tcp stream but not able to ping it or namp scan it directly or with SYN scan

- result when ping to the url :- Name or service not known
- result nmap  when simple full connect scan:-Unable to split netmask from target expression: "https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/codesnippets4all/xss-filter/"
  WARNING: No targets were specified, so 0 hosts scanned.
  Nmap done: 0 IP addresses (0 hosts up) scanned in 0.16 seconds
- result nmap when syn connect:-Unable to split netmask from target expression: "https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/codesnippets4all/xss-filter/"
  WARNING: No targets were specified, so 0 hosts scanned.
- wireshark log

[image]

My question is why can a browser can connect to it but not a ping application or nmap. what is the reason for such a behavior?
Sorry if this is a dumb or a bit redundant question.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Many firewalls block icmp (ping)

Comment: @Xavier59 You really don't want to block all of ICMP. Blocking ICMP type 8 (echo request) may be reasonable, but blocking things like ICMP type 11 (time exceeded) or type 3 (destination unreachable) makes you a bad citizen on the Internet.

Comment: I am not sure publicly announcing you are trying to XSS maven.org is the best of all ideas, and I think you might want to read up on some of the options nmap accepts (https://nmap.org/book/man.html). One good way of getting a sense of what nmap _could_ show you is checking https://shodan.io.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> My question is why can a browser can connect to it

A browser will connect over TCP, by default to a port that is normally open on a web server. Web servers normally use port 80 (plain-text HTTP) or port 443 (HTTPS), and unless the administrator deliberately chooses to use a non-standard port (which then must be specified in the browser address field), any server that is used to serve web content will necessarily have to allow a client to access either or both of these.

> but not a ping application

Ping uses what is technically known as *ICMP Echo Requests* and their corresponding *ICMP Echo Responses*. It is not at all uncommon to block these either at the host level or a perimeter firewall. ICMP is a protocol that runs on top of IP, in the same way as TCP or UDP, but is conceptually considered a sibling of IP rather than a sibling of TCP or UDP. See [RFC 1122 section 1.1.3 Internet Protocol Suite, page 10](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1122#page-10). ICMP is unrelated to HTTP, and being able to connect to a standard HTTP port has no bearing on whether a host will accept a particular ICMP message from the same origin IP address. (Note that ICMP is used for many other things besides ping; it's called the *Internet Control Message Protocol* for good reason. Wikipedia has a handy summary of [all ICMP control messages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Control_Message_Protocol#Control_messages).)

> or nmap

nmap is what is known as a *port scanner* (among several other things). Port scanning is often a high-intensity activity that can easily be detected and subsequently blocked, and I wouldn't be the least bit surprised if many large web sites have just such things in place.

---

**TL;DR:** You are doing completely different things. Getting different results is normal and actually should be expected.